# Different review policies based on path

Tags: azure-devops

I want to know if there is a way to specify different review policies for different paths in the branch. As an example, the documentation folder may not require 2 reviewers unlike a folder which has product code and must be reviewed by 2 or more reviewers.

Is there a provision in Azure DevOps for such configuration?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Different review policies based on path

For this issue ,you can set **Automatically include code reviewers** in the branch policy.

You can select reviewers for specific directories and files in your repo.

[image]

These reviewers are automatically added to pull requests that change files along those paths.

If you select Required, then the pull request can't be completed until:

- Every user added as a reviewer for the path approves the changes.
- At least one person in every group added to the path approves the
  changes.

[image]

You can refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/branch-policies?view=azure-devops#automatically-include-code-reviewers) for details.